# Calculating expected overhead in UDF filesystem

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, udf, optical-media

I'm working on a backup-to-optical-media program that traverses a file tree and adds files to UDF images (`mkisofs` is the backend) to burn to optical discs, splitting large files into chunks across separate images as necessary. As such, I have complete control, to the byte, as far as how much data to include in each UDF image.

**How do I calculate how much space to leave in a UDF image for filesystem overhead?**

Experimentally, I've arbitrarily chosen 5MB for 25GB Bluray images and haven't had an issue yet, but I have no evidence that 5MB is efficient or sufficient for all cases, for example, UDF images with a very large amount of small files.

I'm using UDF 1.02.

Comment: I would also like to know how to estimate the file system overhead based on disc content for UDF discs.

With 24GB of complex directory structures and long files names I've  seen an overhead of several hundreds of MB.